# For part 1 of HSKK高级 exam, do you really need to repeat word for word what is said in the recording?

Tags: hsk

My issue here is that I would struggle even in my mother tongue to repeat word for word a passage I just heard, let alone one in Chinese. Has anyone done this exam yet? Any tips on how to prepare for the first part? I'm assuming that you have the opportunity to write down notes as you hear the passage.

Answer (score 1):

There is some information I found on the internet.

For part I of HSKK(高級), you have better repeat "word to word" and "fluently" what is said in the recording to get the higher score !

---

HSKK 评分说明

**听后复述**

适用试题：HSKK（高级）第 1-3 题。
答题要求：每题播放一段话，要求考生听后复述。

评分档次：

高：考生能完整、流利地复述材料的主要内容，较少停顿和重复。

中：考生能复述部分材料内容，停顿、重复较多，有语法错误。

低：考生复述内容与原材料出入大，语言零乱，信息量小。

http://www.chinesetest.cn/userfiles/file/HSKK-pingfen.pdf

---

录 音 材 料

（音乐，30 秒，渐弱）

你好！你叫什么名字？ （10 秒）
你是哪国人？ （10 秒）
你的序号是多少？ （10 秒）
好，现在开始第 1 到 3 题。每题你会听到一个句子，请在“嘀”声后重复这个句
子。现在开始第 1 题。

1．（2 分钟）

有一天，小李在乡间的小路上开着车。正当他开心地欣赏美丽风景时，突然
迎面开来了一辆货车，更没想到的是，长相奇怪的货车司机还摇下窗户对他大喊
一声：“猪！”小李一听，越想越不明白，也越想越生气，于是他也摇下车窗回头
大骂：“你才是猪！”才刚骂完，他便迎头撞上一群过马路的猪。

2.（2 分钟）
  ...

3.（2 分钟）
 ...

https://ttcn.co.jp/hsk/contents/text/hskkouyugaojimoni9.pdf

Comment: As a Chinese, I don't think I'm able to repeat the content word by word. But I'm pretty sure I can easily tell the story to others after understanding it.

Comment: As A Chinese, I do not take HSK exams. But it content you cited does not require "word to word" repeat, but to use one's own fluent Chinese to tell the same story (or the main story line).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Xuannn I don't have to search for the instruction again. I'll include the quote at the end of this answer.

In the quote, the word used is "复述" but not "背诵". The difference is, with "复述", you retell the story with your own words. With "背诵", you'll have to recite it word by word, character by character.

So no, you do not have to recite it word by word. Just try to understand what the story says, and retell the story in your own words.

Quote:

> HSKK 评分说明
>
> 听后复述
>
> 适用试题：HSKK（高级）第 1-3 题。 答题要求：每题播放一段话，要求考生听后复述。
>
> 评分档次：
>
> 高：考生能完整、流利地复述材料的主要内容，较少停顿和重复。
>
> 中：考生能复述部分材料内容，停顿、重复较多，有语法错误。
>
> 低：考生复述内容与原材料出入大，语言零乱，信息量小。

http://www.chinesetest.cn/userfiles/file/HSKK-pingfen.pdf